# Given $f : U \to V \otimes W$, what is the minimal subspace $W' \subseteq W$ such that $\mathrm{im}(f) \subseteq V \otimes W'$?

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products

Let $(u_i)_{i \in I}$, $(v_j)_{j \in J}$ and $(w_k)_{k \in K}$ be bases of the three vector spaces (which are not necessarily finite dimensional). We can determine $f$ uniquely as $u_i \mapsto \sum_{j,k} f_{ijk} \cdot (v_j \otimes w_k)$ for some $f_{ijk}$ in the ground field. I claim that the span of $\left\{\sum_k f_{ijk}\cdot w_k  \mid (i,j) \in I \times J\right\}$ is the desired subvector space $W'$ of $W$. It clearly does satisfy $\mathrm{im}(f) \subseteq V \otimes W'$, but how to show that it is the unique minimal subspace with this property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question reduces to the following:
**Lemma**:
For any vector $u \in U \otimes V$ , which can be expressed as the following expression:
$$u = \sum_{i}^n v_i \otimes x_i$$
where $(v_i)$ are linearly independent and $x_i$ are non null vector.
If for a subspace $W' \subset W$ we have :
$$u \in U \otimes W' $$
then
$$x_i \in W' \quad \forall i  \quad$$
$\square$

The proof for the above lemma is based on the essential unicity of that kind of expression.
To be more precise, if there are some vectors $v'_1,v'_2,...,v'_m \in V$ and $x'_1,..., x'_m \in W'$ such that:
$$ u = \sum_{i=1}^m v'_i \otimes x'_i$$
and $ (v'_i)$ are linearly independent, $(x'_i)$ non null

Then firstly,  by changing base, we can assume $v'_i$ and $v_i$ are identical  for $i \le min(m,n)$.
Secondly, $m$ and $n$ must be equal  ( = rank of u)
And by unicity of expansion of $u$ in $U\otimes W$, $x'_i$ must be equal to $x_i$
Thus $x_i \in W'$.
Hence, conclusion.

**P/s** Hope there is not any fatal error in my argument.

Comment: Thanks. I find the proof a bit obscure, but I figured that one can also start from a basis of $W'$ and extend it to $W$, and then comparing coefficients for $u$ one sees that the $x_i$ are linear combinations of elements of $W'$. So it works :)

Comment: Nice. Great to hear that